# Comparing types

Tags: c#, types

I have a Generic method where I need to compare the generic type with another type.

The following code always throws the exception:

```
if (!(_vertexType.DataType is T))
   throw new Exception();
```

But this doesn't:

```
if(_vertexType.DataType != default(T).GetType())
   throw new Exception();
```

Why is this? Is there something about the *is* operator I don't understand?

If it helps, the _vertexType.DataType function looks like this:

```
Type DataType
{
   get { return default(myType).GetType(); }
}
```

Tips on how to do it properly would be great too.

Comment: Seems like a bad design when you have to check the type of your input in a generic method to begin with.  Why not use a constraint?

Comment: @Ed How do you mean? The type isn't known at compile time.

Comment: You could also write your statement as `if(_vertexType.DataType != typeof(T))`

Comment: Of course it is; the type is an argument to the generic class/method.  The compiler knows what type it is, that's the whole point and the only way you can have type safety. The whole point of using generic is that your design doesn't care what the type is because it can do its job in a *generic* manner.

Comment: I mean that _vertexType.DataType isn't known at compile time. T obviously is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a `Type` is the class named `Type`, not what it points to. (Hope that made sense!) So you're really checking if the `Type` object representing `Type` is equal to some other `Type` object, and it obviously isn't.

In other words, saying

```
_vertexType.DataType is T
```

is like saying

```
typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(_vertexType.DataType.GetType())
```

but it's obviously not normally true, since calling `GetType()` on a `Type` object gives you a `Type` object representing the `Type` class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof(myType)` instead of the `default(myType).GetType()`. Also your `DataType` is already returning a Type, so you should be using comparison:

```
if(_vertexType.DataType != typeof(T))
   throw new Exception();
```

The `DataType` property is already returning an instance of `Type`, so the only time `_vertexType.DataType is T` will be true is when `T` is `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

`_vertexType.DataType` will only ever be `T` when `T` is of type `Type`, based on your property declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
_vertexType.DataType != default(T).GetType()
```

will always throw a `System.NullReferenceException` if `T` is a reference type.  It will work for value types and structs, because these can't be null and have default values which provides an instance to call `GetType()` on.

The `default` keyword here is basically syntactic sugar (for `null` for reference types and the default value for value types) and translates into an IL OpCode of

```
initobj !!T
```

which, according to the documentation initialises values type with null references and the default values of primitive types.  This also seems to include generic reference types.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx